# Sorting Data in a hasMany relation store Sencha Touch / ExtJS

Tags: sorting, extjs, sencha-touch

I am currently trying to keep a sorted store of Measures (in the musical sense) in app. I am struggling to get the sort functionality of the store to work. I have a model defined with the category of 'index'. My store is also defined as follows:

```
Ext.define('MusicNotationSoftware.store.Measures', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Store',

requires: [
    'Ext.ux.parse.data.proxy.Parse',
    'MusicNotationSoftware.model.Measure'
],

config: {
    model: 'MusicNotationSoftware.model.Measure',
    storeId: 'measuresStore',
    autoLoad: true,
    autoSync: true,
    proxy: {
        type: 'parse',
        url: 'https://api.parse.com/1/classes/Measure'
    },
    sorters: [
        {
            property: 'index',
            direction: 'ASC'
        }
    ],
```

Since measures belong to Voices, I end up calling

```
voice.measures()
```

to get all measures associated with a single voice. To my knowledge this returns a store with all of the measures.

My question then is what is the best way to keep this list of measures sorted as I add measures to the store? Clearly the store that is returned is not the store defined as above.

Answer (score 2):

When you define the measures hasMany association in Voice, you should be able to set up the sorting there:

```
hasMany:[
   {
       model:'MusicNotationSoftware.model.Measure',
       name:'measures',
       storeConfig: {
           sorters: [
               { property: 'index', direction: 'ASC' }
           ]
       }
   }
]
```

or similar.

Answer (score 0):

You dont have to define a store for measures. Since the voice store has already populated measures as measures belong to voice.

All you have to do is call

```
 voice.measures().sort('index', 'ASC')
```

This would sort all the measure record and sort them ascending-ly on the index field.

Answer (score 0):

According to TomW's answer. It should be storeConfig instead of store.

```
hasMany:[
   {
       model:'MusicNotationSoftware.model.Measure',
       name:'measures',
       storeConfig :{
           sorters: [
               { property: 'index', direction: 'ASC' }
           ]
       }
   }
]
```

It worked for me.